# Hide (toggle visibility) of elements between pages

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp-classic

I'm trying to achieve something that I'm not sure is doable. I would like a toggle button to hide/display an element on a page. That is easily done with jQuery. The problem is that I would like the setting to be remembered on the next page I open.

I have 20 pages showing prices on a site. The toggle button should then hide/display the prices on the pages. And I don't want to toggle every time I open a new page, so if I set the toggle button to hide the prices should be hidden on all pages until I hit the button again.

Anyone with an idea of how this could be done easily? It's an ASP page so setting a Session variable is one solution but using jQuery is way cooler since the element is hidden instantly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no end of ways to achieve this, but the method Viridis suggested sounds quite possibly the best way.

- Initialise the visibility of the prices from an ASP Session variable (defaulting to visible)
- Show / Hide the prices using jQuery onClick of a button
- Update the ASP Session variable via a simple ASP page, called via AJAX onClick of the same buttom

This would be a simplified (**and untested**!) version of your asp page :

```
<html>
<head>     
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js" lang="javascript" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script lang="javascript" type="text/javascript">

        //page variable storing the show / hide flag, initialised from the session variable
        <% if Session("hidePrices") = "Y" then %>
            var hidePrices = true;
        <% else %>
            var hidePrices = false;
        <%end if%>

        //worker to actually show / hide the prices
        function showHidePrices(pHidePrices)
        {
            if(pHidePrices)
                $(".myPrices").hide();
            else
                $(".myPrices").show();
        }

        //show / hide prices button click handler
        function showHidePricesOnClick()
        {
            //toggle the flag
            hidePrices = !hidePrices;

            //show / hide the prices
            showHidePrices(hidePrices);

            //toggle the flag stored in the session variable
            $.ajax({
                url: "http://www.yoursite.com/showHidePrices.asp",
                cache: false,
                success:function(result,status,xhr){
                     alert("Called showHidePrices.asp OK!");
                }, 
                error:function(xhr,status,error){
                     alert(xhr.responseText);
                     alert(status);
                     alert(error);
                }                 
            });
        }

        //hide the prices onload if necessary
        $( document ).ready(function() {

            if(hidePrices)
            {
                showHidePrices(true);
            }
        });

    </script>   

</head>
<body>

    <p class="myPrices">price 1</p>
    <p class="myPrices">price 2</p>
    <p class="myPrices">price 3</p>

    <input type="button" onclick="showHidePricesOnClick();" value="Show / Hide Prices"/>

</body>
</html>
```

The code in the showHidePrices.asp page, called via AJAX in the `showHidePricesOnClick` method, would be something like:

```
<%
    if Session("hidePrices") = "Y" then
        Session("hidePrices") = "N"
    else
        Session("hidePrices") = "Y"
    end if
%>
```

As I said, this is untested (and could be done much more elegantly I'm sure), but hopefully will help give you a rough idea of what you'll need to do to achieve what you're after.

Comment: Thank you Ted for posting a complete page! Really appreciated! I understand how the page should work but it looks like the Ajax call isn't working. When I run showHidePrices.asp in the browser the session variable is toggled but not when clicking the button on the main page (your page above) nothng happens. Any idea what might be wrong? I edited the following line, nothing else: url: "showHidePrices.asp".

Comment: I've added some extra error handling to the AJAX call, which will hopefully give you some extra information about why it's failing (e.g. page not found...). The full details on the jQuery AJAX call are here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I've actually tested it for the first time now (a little late, sorry!) and after adding some useful things like a reference to jQuery, some brackets after the showHidePricesOnClick call on the button, and finally, setting the correct path to showHidePrices.asp in the AJAX call, everything worked nicely. Hope you've got it going now too?

Comment: Yes, now it works just fine! Thank's alot! Also, sorry for my terrible spelling in my initial post, must have been in a hurry. Won't happen again :)

Comment: Excellent! Glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1):

You want to do the first toggle using jQuery how you described it.
You then want that jQuery/js to connect to your backend (ASP in your case i assume) and set some value for the current user in your SESSION for example. This way the initial hiding is done smoothly by jQuery/javascript, and afterwards if you ever load a new page, your backend will just not send your the prices, resulting in these prices not showing up at all. (this way you don't have to even think about deleting them using jQuery anymore)

You will have to edit all your 20 pages to suddenly support the 'dont_show_price' parameter ... but it will get you the result you want.